# How to display small popup message that will fadeout after 1-2 seconds when copy text to clipboard?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want that on a button click event it will copy the content of a richtextbox to clipboard and will display a small message like "Copied to clipboard" and that the message will fade out slowly smooth after 1-2seconds.

I tried this but this is with a messagebox and not what i wanted.

also MessageBox don't have the property Close what give error.

```
private void btnCopyInformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(richTextBox1.Text))
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.Text);

        // Show a message for 1-2 seconds
        var message = "Text copied to clipboard!";
        MessageBox.Show(message);

        // Optionally, you can use a timer to close the message after a certain time
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 2000; // 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
        timer.Tick += (s, args) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Close();
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the case where the RichTextBox is empty
        MessageBox.Show("The RichTextBox is empty. Cannot copy.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably need to create a spcialized Form. In the Timer event reduce opacity.

Comment: You could use `await Task.Delay(2000)` instead of creating the timer to close it. But the bulk of the work will be in creating a nice looking form that behaves as you want. Use a timer to animate the opacity/transparancy to get a smooth fadeout.

Answer (score 2):

My working solution.

in form1 in a button click event I'm copying the richTextbox1 content to the clipboard. and also pass the richTextbox1 content to the new formn.

then showing the new form.

```
private void btnCopyInformation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(richTextBox1.Text))
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(richTextBox1.Text);

        FadeForm ff = new FadeForm();
        ff.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

in the new form getting the text and assign to a label.  in the form designer the form and label on same size 192, 82 but in the code I'm setting both label and form size to fit the text length.

then closing the form inside the Load event and using a timer to fade out the form slowly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tests
{
    public partial class FadeForm : Form
    {
        string textToShow;

        public FadeForm(string textToShow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.textToShow = textToShow;
        }

        private void FadeForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblText.Text = textToShow;

            // Use TextRenderer.MeasureText to calculate the required width
            int textWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textToShow, lblText.Font).Width;

            // Set the form width based on the calculated text width
            this.Width = textWidth + 50; // Adjust somePadding based on your preference

            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.ControlBox = false;
            this.Text = "";
            this.Close();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Opacity > 0.01)
                this.Opacity = this.Opacity - 0.01f;
            else
                this.Close();
        }

        private void FadeForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Opacity > 0.01f)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                timer1.Interval = 30;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below :

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class ClipboardPopup : Form
{
    private Label popupLabel;
    private Timer fadeoutTimer;

    public ClipboardPopup(string message)
    {
        InitializeComponents(message);
    }

    private void InitializeComponents(string message)
    {
        // Form settings
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        ShowInTaskbar = false;
        TopMost = true;
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Width - 10, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Height - 10);
        Size = new Size(200, 50);
        Opacity = 0.8;

        // Label settings
        popupLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = message,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 12),
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            BackColor = Color.DarkGreen
        };
        Controls.Add(popupLabel);

        // Timer settings
        fadeoutTimer = new Timer();
        fadeoutTimer.Interval = 2000; // 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds)
        fadeoutTimer.Tick += FadeoutTimer_Tick;
    }

    public void ShowPopup()
    {
        fadeoutTimer.Start();
        Show();
    }

    private void FadeoutTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fadeoutTimer.Stop();
        fadeoutTimer.Dispose();
        Close();
    }
}

class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string textToCopy = "Hello, clipboard!";
        Clipboard.SetText(textToCopy);

        ClipboardPopup popup = new ClipboardPopup("Text copied to clipboard!");
        popup.ShowPopup();

        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: already did my own form and it's working good.  should i post my answer too?  just forgot to post it.  or to accept yours ?